# Is there a way to link eVis with time manager in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, time, qgis-plugins

I have a point vector layer created from way points of a GPS. I then used the eVis plugin to view geotagged photos for each of these point. I also used the time manager plugin to play through the point layer. Is there anyway that as the time manager shows each point that I can see the photo associated with that point?

Thanks for any suggestions!